# Cosa significa "fètola" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Neanche il puzzo che gli mozza il respiro è quello di suo padre. Suo padre puzza di pietra, calce e sudore. Questo è invece puzzo di scarpe, vino e piscio stantio. Porte che sbattono, passi, un rutto eclatante fa tremare le pareti e la tenda che separa lo sgabuzzino da qualche altro locale si spalanca. Lo investe una **fètola** puzzolentissima, uno scroscio di risate e un fiotto di luce.

Non capisco il significato del termine "fètola" in questo brano. L'ho cercato in parecchi dizionari, ma l'ho trovato soltanto nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fetola). Tuttavia,  la definizione che appare là (malattia delle arance e dei mandarini) non sembra avere senso in questo contesto. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "fètola" nel passaggio sopra citato? Si tratta di un vocabolo di origine napoletana?

Comment: Citando la  stessa voce della Treccani: "fètola s. f. [voce di origine merid., di etimo affine a fetente, perché la malattia sarebbe dovuta alla puntura di una cimice di odore sgradevole]" immagino sia un sinonimo di fetore, puzzo, odore sgradevole.

Answer (score 1):

In mancanza di meglio, traduco il mio commento in risposta;

Citando la stessa [voce della Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fetola) indicata nella domanda:

> "fètola s. f. [voce di origine merid., di etimo affine a fetente,
>   perché la malattia sarebbe dovuta alla puntura di una cimice di odore
>   sgradevole]"

immagino sia quindi un sinonimo di fetore, puzzo, odore sgradevole.